# Git repo Push error

Tags: git

I am trying to push my whole react  project folder to git by using command terminal. First I created bare repo in git and on next quick setup window it gave me three options and I am trying the last option. 
Then I move to the project folder in command line and follow these commands

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Azambadar/tic-tac-toe.git
git push -u origin master
```

I got this output

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 39.02 KiB | 3.90 MiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
To https://github.com/Azambadar/tic-tac-toe.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

This only push README.md file to the repo on github nothing else.

What is the reason and how to solve this so all files should be pushed to the repo.

Comment: `git push` operates on commits. Commits are created locally. You need to `git add` changes and then `git commit` them before pushing. Your problem is happening before anything you've shown us. (By the way, your title says "error" but no error is occurring here. Everything looks like it's working properly, except that you forgot to commit some changes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

When you run `git push` command, it will take everything that you have committed (`git commit`) and push it to remote repository. In your case, GitHub.

Take a look at the photo above.

1. When you run `git init`, you are generating `.git` folder. It's hidden folder in your project. If you need to access it, you can go into it by typing `cd .git` in your project root directory. Don't touch anything inside this, unless you are really sure what you are doing. It's advisable not to touch this folder.
2. After you finish with a task, you should add the file(s) first by typing `git add` command. For example, `git add single-file.html` or `git add .` to add all changed files.
3. The 'added' files will go to 'staging area'. If you run `git push` command here, you are not pushing the recent changes yet.
4. Next, you need to 'finalize' everything that you have inside the 'staging area' by running `git commit` command. For example, `git commit -m "fix broken links"`. Now you are ready to go.
5. Run `git push` or `git push origin master` command and you will see the changes in the GitHub.

**Notes**

1. You only need to run `git init` commit once for every project.
2. If you are cloning a project from GitHub, you just need to run `git clone` command. You don't have to `cd the-project` and run `git init` inside it. When you are cloning a project from a remote Git repository, you automatically have the `.git` folder.
3. You can also use GUI tool like [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) if you find yourself more productive working with GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

Do `git status` to see which files you have not marked for a commit yet.
Then mark files you want to commit with `git add yourFile`.
Then you need to create the commit with a git message `git commit -m "your commit message"`.
And finally you can do `git push`